# Subtotal include tax in order email magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-email

I must have the subtotal with taxes included, but I can not find where to set it.
I search in all file template, but without success.

thanks

[image: **subtotal**]

Answer (score 1):

Hi Biagio and welcome to MageOverflow. You can configure this in the backend:

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Tax

> Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings > Display Subtotal
```

[image]